# Visual studio project directory issue

Tags: c#, directory

I'm writing to a text folder which is in a folder within my project but I can't seem to get to it without writing the absolute complete path as it is on my computer which is fine on this computer but when I want to take it elsewhere I can't have that as the drives are different etc.

Here is a screenshot of the lines I'm using to get it to post to the directory on the right.

The file I'm trying to access is in a folder called AdminAccount and is called User.txt. it works fine as you can see from the commented directory link as a direct path but when I try with the directory string in use it does not work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KemD.png

Any help how to get around this? I tried all sorts, I tried doing

```
private string[] getLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"\AdminAccount\User.txt");
private string[] getLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"..\AdminAccount\User.txt");
```

No joy.

Comment: what is your current folder? imean from which file you are writing above lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
string rootPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string filePath = Path.Combine(rootPath,@"..\..\AdminAccount\User.txt");
private string[] getLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@filePath);
```

`..\` is used to access a top level folder in the hierarchy. you can keep on adding `..\` to move up in the hierarchy.

Ex:

```
string path1 = @"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test\Test\bin\Debug"
string newPath = Path.Combine(path1, @"..\..\AdminAccount\User.txt");
```

new path would return 
`C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test\Test\AdminAccount\User.txt`

Comment: Lovely explanation. Really appreciate it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the property **"Copy to Output Directory"** of the "User.txt" file to **"Copy allways"** or **"Copy if newer"**.

Now you can read the lines as below

```
string[] getLines = File.ReadAllLines(
                 Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "AdminAccount", "User.txt"));
```